# Error while sorting in pymongo

Tags: mongodb, sorting, mongodb-query, pymongo

In mongoshell, the below statement is working fine:

```
db.grades.find({'type':'homework'}).sort({$score:1})
```

But when I am trying to do same in pymongo, i am facing an error:

```
itr= collection.find({'type':'homework'}).sort(['score', pymongo.ASCENDING])
```

Error:

```
    for (key, value) in index_list:
    ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this always confuses me too.

You need to pass into `sort` *a list of pairs*, and you're passing a list of length 2 (i.e. a pair).

This should work:

```
itr= collection.find({'type':'homework'}).sort([ ['score', pymongo.ASCENDING] ])
```

The idea is that you can pass more than one pair in your list (for secondary order, etc.).